# Как лучше реализовать обновление кроссплатформенного приложения

Tags: c#, linux, github, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

У меня есть готовый проект написанный на Visual Studio 2019 C#. Мне нужно запускать его на линуксе, там он работает, но в данный момент для обновления версии я компилирую его и переношу флешкой, это неудобно. Проект загружен на github. Есть ли возможность обновлять скомпилированную версию через github(линукс - ubuntu)? Хочу сделать что-то вроде:

1. Делаю коммит из VS
2. Выпускаю релиз на Github
3. В линуксе что-то типо `apt-get update`
4. И все круто обновляется и работает)

Comment: Azure Devops вам в помощь. Сам соберет, сам опубликует. Вам остается лишь настроить сборку и публикацию, ну и написать в приложение механизм скачивания и обновления.

Comment: [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions). | Вообще, это можно делать скриптом (на любом языке, я делал на PowerShell).